# get toast message from its Toast object

Tags: android, testing, toast

Is there a way to get the message associated with a particular android Toast object in android?

```
toast=Toast.makeText(getAppContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

now in my test class i want to get the message from this toast object

Comment: try this  String displayedText = ((TextView)((LinearLayout)toast.getView()).getChildAt(0)).getText().toString();

Comment: Your Toast is custom Toast or default one ? You can try some tweaks with getView() method

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to get the message associated with a particular android
>   Toast object in android?

Do it as:

```
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getAppContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
View view = toast.getView(); 
TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
String strMessage=tv.getText().toString();
```